# Will this quantity converge to zero?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Assume you have $n$ iid random variables $\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\}$. The may not necessarily have finite variance, but they do have finite mean. Let $\mu = E(X)$. Will then the quantity

$$E\left(\left|\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{X_i-\mu}{n}\right|\right),$$
converge to zero? I know that if they had finite variance then we could using Hölder's inequality show that the quantity converges to zero. However, I am unsure what happens when the variance may be infinite.

The motivation for this question is showing that the quantity

$$P\left(\left|\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}-\mu\right|\ge\epsilon\right)\rightarrow0,$$
for any $\epsilon>0$, when the variance of each $X_i$ may not be finite. Will this quantity go to zero?

Comment: the strong law of large numbers show us that $\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ converges to $\operatorname{E}[X_1]$ almost sure if the $X_k$ are iid and that $\operatorname{E}[X_1]$ exists (maybe being infinite), however the proof of this theorem is not so easy

Comment: @Masacroso Thank you, that means that the second quantity cconverges to zero?, but what about the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. $\lim_{n\to\infty} E\left[\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{t=1}^n (X_t - \mu)\right|\right] = 0$.

Assume without loss of generality that $\mu = 0$ and let $Y_n = \left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{t=1}^n X_n\right|$. As another reader pointed out, the law of large numbers shows that $\lim_{n\to\infty} Y_n = 0$ almost surely, which implies that $Y_n$ converges to $0$ in probability.

Given a sequence $(Y_n)$ converging to $0$ in probability, a necessary and sufficient condition that it converges in mean is that $(Y_n)$ are uniformly integrable (UI). That is (a) there exists an $M$ such that $E[Y_n] \leq M$ for all $n$ and (b) for $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all measurable $A$ with $P(A) < \delta$ it holds that $\sup_n E[1_A|Y_n|] \leq \epsilon$.

Since $(X_n)$ are iid and $E[|X_1|] < \infty$ by assumption, it is easy to check that $(X_n)$ are UI. It remains to show that $(Y_n)$ are UI. Checking condition (a) is easy. Let $M = E[|X_1|]$, which exists by assumption. Then $E[Y_n] \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{t=1}^n E[|X_n|] \leq M$.

For the second condition (b), let $\epsilon > 0$ and let $\delta$ be such that for all $A$ with $P(A) < \delta$, $\sup_n E[1_A |X_n|] \leq \epsilon$. Therefore
$\sup_n E[1_A Y_n] = \sup_n E\left[1_A \left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{t=1}^n X_t\right|\right] \leq \sup_n \frac{1}{n} \sum_{t=1}^n E\left[1_A |X_n|\right] \leq \epsilon$. Therefore $(Y_n)$ are UI and converge in probability to zero from which we can conclude that $\lim_n E[Y_n] = 0$ as required.